# Firefox Developer Edition - Delete Cookie

Tags: windows, firefox

How do I delete a cookie in Firefox Developer Edition?

(Not a good sign for this product that this question needs to be asked).

I'm using v35.0a2 (2014-11-14) on Windows.

Comment: Which version of FF Dev is in question? Which OS?

Comment: This is for 35.0a2 (2014-11-14) Windows.

Comment: Why can't you can go to the location of the Firefox user profile and delete the cookie by hand.

Comment: @Ramhound As a browser that touts itself as "a browser for developers" I find your suggestion an unacceptable solution. The Storage tab lists all the cookies for the page/domain you're on, am I not right-clicking hard enough?

Comment: Your also using a preview version of said "browser for developers" so you might have to cut some corners.  Of course you also asked how delete a cookie.

Comment: Fair enough. I was excited for this release, but I suppose I will have to contain my excitement until it is a usable product.

Answer (score 1):

Aha. I knew this couldn't have been left out.

F2 to open Developer Toolbar.

Then you can use `cookie list` on the command line. This will list each cookie and provide a `Remove` button.

Comment: Remove button does not seem to work on Mac version :-/

Answer (score 0):

Remove button does not seem to work on Mac version :-/

- click the "remove" button
- new code appears on the command line
- click the Return key on your Mac
- and the cookie is gone

If your site has more than one cookie or you are doing this a lot because you are developing something, consider getting a plugin to reduce the number of steps to one.